# jQuery, need help with 'sortreceive' ajax call and POST vars

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a dilemma that just seems beyond my abilities at the moment!

I have a group of connected sortables using the class 'biglist'.

What I want to do is bind #biglist 's sortreceive callback (which is made whenever a list receives an element from another) to take the 'boxnum' value of the element (which signifies which list its coming from) and perform an UPDATE query changing the id's boxnum value from say 5(list it came from) to 7 (list its been dragged to) so that the state persists.

So the exchange would happen like so (roughly)

```
$( "#biglist" ).bind( "sortreceive", function(event, ui) {
  ajax call to boxchange.php
  create vars to represent elements 'boxnum' value and 'box moved to' value     

});
```

Then inside boxchange.php ->

```
 $id = $_POST['id']
 $box = $_POST['boxnum']
 ->update query SET boxid to new boxid WHERE id = posted ID of element
```

I hope this makes sense. It seems like a pretty slick way to make my program work!
Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
EDIT:
```

Just cleaned up the function to see if there are any changes that need to be made to it (which I know there are, because it looks sloppy) This function would need to be copied/altered for each sortable separately but it'd totally make the program work at least!

```
function ReceiveTwo() 
{
$('#sortable2').bind('sortreceive', function(event, ui) 
                    {
                        boxnum = $(this).attr('boxnum');
                        id = $(this).attr('id');
                       $.ajax
                            ({
                        url: "boxchange.php",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: boxnum, id,
                        success : function(feedback)
                            {
                            $('#data').html(feedback)
                            }

                            })
                    });
                    $('#sortable2').sortable("refresh");
});
```

Comment: it is unclear what part of it is not working for you, also you said "I have a group of connected sortables using the _class_ 'biglist'." but you are using #biglist it should be .biglist if it is a class.

Comment: My bad, I had a feeling I'd get replies like mkoryak.

I'm wondering how to send two sets of data with the ajax call (the way I wrote it in that example doesn't match syntax afaik)

I want boxnum and id defined before I make the call so I know what to send, then after I specifiy the type of request (POST) I need to be able to send the two values to my php script to update the DB.

Does this make sense? If not it'll just re-affirm my horrible grip on asking these types of questions in ways other people will understand :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#sortable2').bind('sortreceive', function(event, ui) {
   $.ajax({
     url: "boxchange.php",
     type: "POST",
     beforesend: function(){
        boxnum = $(this).attr('boxnum');
        id = $(this).attr('id');
     },
     data: {'boxnum': boxnum, 'id': id},
     success : function(feedback) {
        $('#data').html(feedback),
     }
   });
});
```

beforesend is the event that fires before the ajax call. I believe here you could set your properties to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you want to send your Javascript data to your server-side PHP script is using a Javascript associative array, like so:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "boxchange.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {'boxnum': boxnum, 'id': id},
  success: function(data,status) { ... }
```

Your "boxchange.php" script would then be able to access those variables via $_POST['boxnum'] and $_POST['id'].

I think that was your goal, but I'm not entirely sure...

Comment: Very close, I need to make sure I'm defining 'boxnum' properly before sending it off in the ajax call as 'boxnum'.

So $(this).attr('id') works fine for the current ID of the element being dragged - however $(this).parent.attr('boxnum') isn't grabbing the boxnumber of the list that's receiving the element.

I need to grab that variable so I can send it to my php query to change a value to that number :)

Comment: Ok to be 100% specific this time!

The program is 'borked' when it comes to the success function and feedback. It just makes it so NONE of the items display in their lists...both are just empty.